# Client cannot receive UDP message

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I am a beginner of socket programming using python. I am working on my course project. Part of my project requires sending and receiving UDP messages with different port. The server program called robot is provided and I need to write the client program called student which can interact with the robot. Thus, I cannot show all source code in the server program.

This is the part related to the UDP socket in the server program

```
############################################################################# phase 3
# Create a UDP socket to send and receive data
print ("Preparing to receive x...")
addr = (localhost, iUDPPortRobot)
s3 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s3.bind(addr)

x, addr = s3.recvfrom(1)
print ("Get x = %d" % (int(x)))
############################################################################# phase 3

time.sleep(1)
print ("Sending UDP packets:")

messageToTransmit = ""
for i in range(0,int(x) * 2):
    messageToTransmit += str(random.randint(0,9999)).zfill(5)
print ("Message to transmit: " + messageToTransmit)

for i in range(0,5):
    s3.sendto(messageToTransmit.encode(),(studentIP,iUDPPortStudent))
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("UDP packet %d sent" %(i+1))
    
############################################################################# phase 4
```

This is my client program. s3 is the UDP socket. I can send message to the server program successfully but I cannot receive the message from it. Is this due to the difference in the ports? If yes, what should I do in order to fix it?

```
import os
import subprocess
import socket
import random
import time

sendPort = 3310
localhost = '127.0.0.1'
socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)

command = "python robot_for_python_version_3.py"
subprocess.Popen(command)
print("ROBOT IS STARTED")

sendSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sendSocket.connect((localhost, sendPort))
studentId = '1155127379'
sendSocket.send(studentId.encode())

s_2Port = sendSocket.recv(5)
sendSocket.close()

s_2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s_2.bind((localhost, int(s_2Port)))
s_2.listen(5)
s2, address = s_2.accept()
s_2.close()

step4Port = s2.recv(12)
iUDPPortRobot, dummy1 = step4Port.decode().split(",")
iUDPPortStudent, dummy2 = dummy1.split(".")

s3 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
num = random.randint(5,10)
time.sleep(3)
s3.sendto(str(num).encode(), (localhost, int(iUDPPortRobot)))
print("Test1")

charStr = s3.recvfrom(1024)
print("Test2")
print(charStr)



exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not receiving the message is because the server sends it to an endpoint that is not listening for messages. As the protocol is UDP (no guarantees, etc.), the server sends the message successfully to a non-listening endpoint, while the listening endpoint waits forever.

In more detail, `addr` as returned by `x, addr = s3.recvfrom(1)` is **not** `(studentIP, iUDPPortStudent)`. Try the following to see the difference (note that you have omitted the piece where `iUDPPortRobot` is defined and shared, I set it to 50000 for illustration purposes):

```py
# in one interactive session 1 (terminal), let's call it session 1 
>>> import socket
>>> import random 
>>> import time
>>> 
>>> iUDPPortRobot = 50000
>>> addr = ('localhost', iUDPPortRobot)
>>> s3 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s3.bind(addr)
>>> x, addr = s3.recvfrom(1) # <= this will block

# in another interactive session (terminal), let's call it session 2
>>> import socket
>>> import random 
>>> import time
>>> 
>>> iUDPPortRobot = 50000
>>> s3 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> num = random.randint(5,10)
>>> s3.sendto(str(num).encode(), ('localhost', int(iUDPPortRobot))) # <= this will unblock recvfrom in session 1, i.e., the message got received
1

# back to session 1
>>> addr <= check address, this is the main issue you are facing
('127.0.0.1', 60911)
>>> messageToTransmit = ""
>>> for i in range(0,int(x) * 2):
...     messageToTransmit += str(random.randint(0,9999)).zfill(5)
... 
>>> print ("Message to transmit: " + messageToTransmit)
Message to transmit: 06729020860821106419048530205105224040360495103025

# back to session 2, let's prepare for receiving the message
>>> charStr = s3.recvfrom(1024) # <= this will block 

# back to session 1 to send a message
# you do not share what (studentIP,iUDPPortStudent), but from 
# what you describe it is not ('127.0.0.1', 60911), let's say
# studentIP = 'localhost' and iUDPPortStudent = 50001
>>> studentIP = 'localhost'
>>> iUDPPortStudent = 50001
# now let send a message that will be sent successfully but not received, i.e.,
# it will not unblock recvfrom in session 2
>>> s3.sendto(messageToTransmit.encode(),(studentIP,iUDPPortStudent))
50
# ... but if try to send to the listening endpoint it will get received
>>> s3.sendto(messageToTransmit.encode(), addr)
50

# back to session 2, to check things
>>> charStr
(b'06729020860821106419048530205105224040360495103025', ('127.0.0.1', 50000)) # <= SUCCESS
```

There are two ways to fix this. The one shown above which involves changing the server code, which essentially involves what is shown above, i.e., send the message to a listening endpoint by modifying the address passed to `s3.sendto`. If I understand things correctly, this is not an option as you are trying to write the client code. The second way is to send the message to `(studentIP, iUDPPortStudent)`, but have a listening endpoint at the other end. If `studentIP` and `iUDPPortStudent` are known to your "client" program, which I assume is the case, you can add code similar to what you have at the top of the server program code snippet.

Specifically, add in place of `charStr = s3.recvfrom(1024)` something like:

```py
addr = (studentIP, iUDPPortStudent)
s4 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s4.bind(addr)

charStr = s4.recvfrom(1024) # <= this will block and unblock when you send the message using s3.sendto(messageToTransmit.encode(),(studentIP,iUDPPortStudent))
```

For completeness, you will need to change `localhost` to `'localhost'` and if in your experiments you encounter a `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use` you will have to wait for the `TIME-WAIT` period to pass or set the `SO_REUSEADDR` flag by adding `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` **before** `bind`.